# Datasource not binding properly to DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to set the datasource of a DataGridView called `FileGridView` to a `List<object>` called `filesAndDirectories`, which contains a list of `DirectoryProperties` objects and `FileProperties` objects, the variables in which are shown below:

**DirectoryProperties**

```
private string _directoryname;
private string _directorytype;
private string _directorysize;
private string _dateCreated;
private string _dateModified;
```

**FileProperties**

```
private string _filename;
private string _filetype;
private string _filesize;
private string _dateCreated;
private string _dateModified;
```

**Binding list to datasource**

```
FileGridView.DataSource = files;
```

When this list is passed to be the datasource of `FileGridView` however, none of the data shows up. Oddly enough, however, the correct number of rows and columns to display the data ARE being shown.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? The list is obviously having some impact, I'm just not sure why the grid isn't updating.

**FileGridView Properties**

```
// 
            // FileGridView
            // 
            this.FileGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.FileGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            this.FileGridView.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
            this.FileGridView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.FileGridView.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.ColName,
            this.ColType,
            this.ColSize,
            this.ColDateCreated,
            this.ColDateModified});
            this.FileGridView.EditMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
            this.FileGridView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 38);
            this.FileGridView.MultiSelect = false;
            this.FileGridView.Name = "FileGridView";
            this.FileGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            this.FileGridView.ShowEditingIcon = false;
            this.FileGridView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(503, 376);
            this.FileGridView.TabIndex = 4;
            this.FileGridView.CellContentDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.FileGridView_CellContentDoubleClick);
```

### Link to project

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14954037/SharpManager.rar

Comment: Have you called `FileGridView.DataBind();`

Comment: @Vishal : that doesn't seem to be a method within FileGridView

Comment: Sorry, I have not used winforms for long time. Currently I work on WPF as well as ASP.Net. In ASP.Net GridView has a method called DataBind(). So, I thought there will be same method in Winforms. Sorry......

Comment: Please keep a breakpoint on this line : `FileGridView.DataSource = files;` and run your program. Check if your files variable has some data in it?

Comment: @Vishal : Yeah, it shows that the data is in there. Curious as to why it doesn't actually appear in the DataGridView...

Comment: Close Visual Studio, restart it, delete DataGridView and Add it again. This might be a visual-studio bug. If needed restart your computer.

Comment: Can you upload your project? or can you create a small sample application and upload? I will try to look at your problem and possibly any other developer may also try to find the problem in it.

Comment: Sure thing, here it is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14954037/SharpManager.rar I'll put it in the main body of the post too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
private string _filename;
```

is a private field.  You have to make them public properties in order for the DataGridView to use them properly:

```
public string Filename {get; set; }
```

If your columns already exist in the DataGridView control, then you have to assign the class property before you set the grid's DataSource property:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Filename";
```

Answer (score 1):

The DataGridView will generate columns automatically if AutoGenerateColumns is true, which it is by default, it will only generate columns for public properties though, not for your private fields.

This would explain why your control knows your number of elements, but not how to show them.

edit:

Okay I managed to get some data showing. Having public properties seems necessary,

```
public string _directoryname { get; set; }
```

works,

```
private string _directoryname;
```

does not. Also, having both FileProperties and DirectoryProperties in your list works initially but crashes when you scroll down to actually show the directoryproperties. You should make a base-class or interface that both your classes inherit from / implement, that contains what you need to show them.

Comment: The columns were put in to start with because there's always going to be 5 columns in this, it's just the rows that are being generated as and when. Would setting those variables to public work, then?

Comment: Can you post all the code for the DataGridView so we can have a look? Even if the columns don't need to be autogenerated, I think they'll require you to have public properties.

Comment: Yes, at least the parts that might be relevant if there's a lot of code.

Comment: Thanks. Added some more information in my post that'll help you get your data showing.

Comment: I see it, cheers. Yeah, I ended up just swapping them both to using the FileProperties, they were pretty much the same things anyway. Can't find out how to get the directory's size through a method though, which is annoying... but I'm alright without it!

Answer (score 0):

List does not implement IBindingList so the grid does not know about your new items.

Bind your DataGridView to a BindingList instead.

```
var blist = new BindingList<object>(your_file_list);
myGrid.DataSource = blist;
```

Comment: try using BindingSource instead of BindingList

Comment: How would I convert a list so it's able to be put in a BindingSource?